# Table in LaTeX can't show everything

Tags: latex, tabular

I am trying to use `tabularray` in Latex to put all the elements in the array to the center of each cell.

```
\begin{tblr}{vlines={}, hlines{}}
\hline
& Dog & Car & Bird \\
\hline
\SetCell[r=3]{} \includegraphics[scale=0.075]{Images/Dog/dog0.png} & 
\SetCell[r=3]{} 9.9878e-01 & \SetCell[r=3]{} 1.184e-03 & \SetCell[r=3]{} 3.4918e-05 \\
\hline
\SetCell[r=3]{} \includegraphics[scale=0.075]{Images/Car/car0.png} & 
\SetCell[r=3]{} 1.9827e-06 & \SetCell[r=3]{} 1.000e+00 & \SetCell[r=3]{} 1.2906e-06 \\
\hline
\SetCell[r=3]{} \includegraphics[scale=0.075]{Images/Bird/bird0.png} & 
\SetCell[r=3]{} 2.5124e-05 & \SetCell[r=3]{} 1.5071e-05 & \SetCell[r=3]{} 9.9996e-01 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
```

However, I am not getting the whole table. I can only see the first and second row after compile.
[image]

What have I done wrong?

I think the second row took all the spaces for the third and fourth row. (I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the `\SetCell[r=3]{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{vlines,hlines}
& Dog & Car & Bird \\
 \includegraphics[scale=0.75,valign=c]{example-image-duck} & 
 9.9878e-01 &  1.184e-03 &  3.4918e-05 \\
 \includegraphics[scale=0.75,valign=c]{example-image-duck} & 
 1.9827e-06 &  1.000e+00 &  1.2906e-06 \\
 \includegraphics[scale=0.75,valign=c]{example-image-duck} & 
 2.5124e-05 &  1.5071e-05 &  9.9996e-01 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. So am I right about the second row covered the third and fourth row?

Comment: @henryChan basically yes, tabularray ignored the entries from the 3rd and 4th row because it was instructed that the second row would be 3 rows height.